# Predict next time series data point (time and value)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, statistics, data-modeling, prediction

I have time series data that associates a measurement to the time. Suppose that it is an app where a user enters their height whenever they want. Based on past behavior, I not only what to predict what their next height measurement is, but I also want to predict *when* the measurement will be entered.

Sample data for a single person:

```
    Date     | Measurement
-------------|------------
Nov 8,  2014 | 1.42 m
Nov 23, 2014 | 1.43 m
Mar 8,  2015 | 1.48 m
Jun 15, 2015 | 1.52 m
Dec 18, 2015 | 1.52 m
Mar 1,  2016 | 1.59 m
Nov 8,  2016 | 1.60 m
```

What I want to predict is the next data point in this series. For example, it might be (Dec 8, 2016, 1.61 m).

My initial thoughts have been to make two separate models, one that is simply the time data with x values being indices. For example

```
0 | Nov 8,  2014
1 | Nov 23, 2014
2 | Mar 8,  2015
3 | Jun 15, 2015
4 | Dec 18, 2015
5 | Mar 1,  2016
6 | Nov 8,  2016
```

(where the dates have been converted to minutes since 1970 or something).

Use this model to predict the next time point, then the original model to predict, at that time point, what will be the measurement.

In terms of algorithms to use I was thinking to use a Kalman filter for both models.

My question is that I feel like I am missing something, or possibly over complicating this problem. Does anyone have an idea for an alternative solution?

I will be implementing in javascript with hopefully no external libraries.

Comment: "that I feel like I am missing something" You are aware about the risks, right? ["By late next month, you'll have over 4 dozen husbands"](https://xkcd.com/605/) springs to mind.

Comment: Yes, haha, I am aware. The scenario I showed here is sample data, and I expect my actual data to be more reliable and predictable. That's a great point, though.

Comment: Not sure what's the best method, you should probably compare various methods by backtesting, I would anyway try using the measurements results as well for predicting the time of the next measurement.